# Linux shell script to find and rename files to remove suffix?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have some files named like this:

file1.c.keep.apple

file2.c.keep.apple

I am trying to write a shell script so that I pass in the suffix as an argument (in this case, `apple`) and it will rename all of the files removing the `.keep.apple`.

Example execution:

`script.sh apple`

results in the files above being renamed to

file1.c

file2.c

So far, I have

```
 #! /bin/sh
 find . -type f -name \'*.keep.$1\' -print0 | xargs -0 rename 's/\(.keep.*)$//'
```

and the files do not get renamed. I know the `find` portion is correct. I am thinking the regex on my rename is wrong. How can I get the script working the way I want?

Comment: Does it need to be done recursively through several sub directories?

Comment: yes, sorry. I want it to work when I execute this script from a directory, and it searches the current dir and all subdirs.

Comment: Check my edited answer, it seems to do what you want.

Comment: Updated my answer again based on your needs and comments made by Uwe Kleine-König. You should review the answers and comments again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated, try this perhaps:

```
#!/bin/bash

SUFFIX=$1;

find . -type f -name "*keep.${SUFFIX}" | while read -r file;
do 
    nfile=`echo $file | sed "s/\.keep\.${SUFFIX}//g"`; 
    mv "$file" "$nfile" 2>/dev/null; 
done
```

here it is running:

```
jgalley@jgalley-debian:/test5$ cat replace.sh 
#!/bin/bash

SUFFIX=$1;

find . -type f -name "*keep.${SUFFIX}" | while read -r file;
do 
    nfile=`echo $file | sed "s/\.keep\.${SUFFIX}//g"`; 
    mv "$file" "$nfile" 2>/dev/null; 
done
jgalley@jgalley-debian:/test5$ find .
.
./-filewithadash.keep.apple
./dir1
./dir1/file
./dir1/file2.keep.orange
./dir2
./dir2/file2
./file with spaces
./file.keep.orange
./file.keep.somethingelse.apple
./file.orange
./replace.sh
jgalley@jgalley-debian:/test5$ ./replace.sh apple
jgalley@jgalley-debian:/test5$ find .
.
./-filewithadash
./dir1
./dir1/file
./dir1/file2.keep.orange
./dir2
./dir2/file2
./file with spaces
./file.keep.orange
./file.keep.somethingelse.apple
./file.orange
./replace.sh
jgalley@jgalley-debian:/test5$
```

Comment: This doesn't address the ".keep" part but uses "file" instead, though. Also note that this doesn't work if the filenames contain spaces (which might or might not be important)

Comment: I didn't test, but I'd say you need `sed "s/.keep.${SUFFIX}//"`. And this is still broken as `.` is special.

Comment: I changed the find command to be "*.keep.$1" and the sed to be "s/.keep.${SUFFIX}//g" and its working for me!!

Comment: @unexpected62: you want to quote the dots and add a $ at the end for the sed expression, yielding: `s/\.keep\.${SUFFIX}$//`. Otherwise you will have funny results on filenames like `file.keep.applepie.keep.apple`.

Comment: I found another thing that could be bad :-) If you have a filename starting with `-` the `echo` and `mv` commands might not do what they should.

Comment: @Uwe Kleine-König dashes shouldn't be a problem actually, i've updated my answer to display this in the test.

Comment: jesse_galley: you're right because you only get paths from find starting with `./`

Answer (score 4):

> I know the `find` portion is correct

Except it isn't.

```
find . -type f -name "*.keep.$1" -print0 | ...
```

Comment: I had it as `\'*.keep.$1\'` so that the $1 was recognized as an argument. With your solution isn't it going to look for the string literal `$1` in the filename?

Comment: No, it isn't. And as an added bonus it won't let spaces in `$1` destroy your system.

Comment: Oh, interesting. Thanks. Regardless, the xargs portion must be wrong because the script still doesn't work with your change.

Comment: Your parens are unbalanced.

Comment: With `\'*.keep.$1\'` you search for files who's name start with `'`.

Comment: This "answer" seems like a comment to me.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you need:

```
find . -type f -name "*.keep.$1" -print0 | xargs -0 rename "s/\.keep\.$1$//"
```

Note the following limitations:

- rename might not be available everywhere.
- `find -print0` and `xargs -0` are GNU extensions which might not be available on all Unixes.
- if your first parameter contains characters that are special for regexes the result might not what you want. (e.g. `yourscript "a*e"`)

Comment: @unexpected62: hmm, works for me (even before I made the command more robust with some edits after your comment). I did: `mkdir adir; touch adir/file2.c.keep.apple; touch file1.c.keep.apple; set apple; find . -type f -name "*.keep.$1" -print0 | xargs -0 rename "s/\.keep\.$1$//"`

Comment: what does $1 stand for in your scripts

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
[spatel@us tmp]$ x=aa.bb.cc
[spatel@us tmp]$ y=${x%.cc}
[spatel@us tmp]$ echo $y
aa.bb


[spatel@us tmp]$ x=aa.bb.cc
[spatel@us tmp]$ y=${x%.bb.cc}
[spatel@us tmp]$ echo $y
aa
```

Comment: This is brilliant! I have used Linux for 26 years and yet did not know this. 
More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34951901/percent-symbol-in-bash-whats-it-used-for#34952009).

Answer (score 1):

If you can assume bash, and a version of bash greater then 4 (with globstar support), here is a clean bash-only solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

(($#)) || exit 1

shopt -s globstar nullglob
for f in **/*.keep."$1"; do
    mv -- "$f" "${f%.keep.$1}"
done
```

Alternatively, here is a solution using `find` and a `while read` loop (assumes GNU or BSD find):

```
find . -type f -name "*.keep.$1" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do
    mv -- "$f" "${f%.keep.$1}"
done
```

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/030 for more details on this solution.

Also, you can implement what you are trying to do using `find` with `-exec`:

```
find . -type f -name "*.keep.$1" -exec sh -c 'mv -- "$2" "${2%.keep.$1}"' _ "$1" {} ';'
```

Comment: In the last `find` solution: in the exec statement, you probably mean `bash -c 'mv -- "$1" "${1%.keep.$0}"' "$1" {}`. And it fails in some ways if either `$1` is `*` or if `$1` is `;`

Comment: No, I meant what I typed.  The only differences between what I wrote and what you had suggested is the use of 'bash', and a shift of the positional parameters.  'bash' is not necessary, since POSIX sh supports parameter expansion; your shift of positional parameters is not necessary, nor relevant.

And, in fact, including '*' characters in the suffix works just fine, since the shell does not do glob expansion when arguments are inside double quotes.

Comment: I came across this solution while searching on net for some thing I am not clear with use of 'mv -- "$2" "${2%.keep.$1}"' what does ${2%.keep.$1} and $2 stand for and use of underscore in your solution  "$1" {} and then use of ';' what kind of syntax is this

Comment: `${2%.keep.$1}` is a parameter expansion (see the bash man page); this PE expands to the value of `$2` with the suffix `.keep.$1` removed ($1 is expanded here before the removal).
To better understand how `$1` and `$2` are set here, it helps to understand how `sh -c` works.  `sh -c 'echo "$1"' _ "hello, world!"` , for example, will spawn a shell to run the 'echo "$1"' command string, and set the positional arguments to: `$0 = _; $1 = "hello, world!"`  (the underscore is there as a placeholder for `$0`).  The rest is wrapping this all up with `find`.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you can simply glob the files, you can do just

```
rename '.keep.apple' '' *
```

otherwise you would replace the `*` with the `find` + `xargs` you already have.

Note in this by `rename` is meant `rename` from `util-linux`. On some systems it is installed like `rename.ul` instead of `rename`.