# percent symbol in Bash, what's it used for?

Tags: bash

I have a filename which ends with `.zip` and I wanted just the filename without zip. Here I found a trick in bash.

```
$f="05 - Means-End Analysis Videos.zip"
$echo "${f%*.zip}"
05 - Means-End Analysis Videos
```

What is happening here? How come `%*.zip` is removing my extension?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html Third section from bottom.

Comment: Have a  look here [bash manipulating with strings percent sign](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444004/bash-manipulating-with-strings-percent-sign)

Comment: Also, the `*` is superfluous (always matches nothing when used after single `%`).

Comment: note that another usage of the `%` character in bash is if a program such as `vim` is suspended with `ctrl-z`, then the `%vim` command resumes it, like `fg`.

Comment: As already noted in
[another comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34951901#comment57635748_34951901),
the `*` does not make much sense.
The snippet `"${f%*.zip}"` means keep the content of `f`, but remove
the last occurrence of `.zip`. * ~ * ~ *
So in `"05 - Means-End Analysis Videos.zip"` simply cut out `.zip` to
get `"05 - Means-End Analysis Videos"`.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Delete the shortest match of `string` in `$var` from the beginning:

```
${var#string}
```

Delete the longest match of `string` in `$var` from the beginning:

```
${var##string}
```

Delete the shortest match of `string` in `$var` from the end:

```
${var%string}
```

Delete the longest match of `string` in `$var` from the end:

```
${var%%string}
```

Try:

```
var=foobarbar
echo "${var%b*r}"
> foobar
echo "${var%%b*r}"
> foo
```

Comment: This answer is fine, although any interested reader coming here may want to compare it with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536935) (which is slightly more elaborated I would say).