# Replacing multiple preceding numbers from files

Tags: bash, glob

Good day,

I have a bunch of files that need to be batch renamed like so:

```
 01-filename1.txt    > filename1.txt
 02-filename2.txt    > filename2.txt
 32-filename3.txt    > filename3.txt
 322-filename4.txt   > filename4.txt
 31112-filename5.txt > filename5.txt
```

I run into an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34951901/percent-symbol-in-bash-whats-it-used-for) of achieving this using bash  [***${string#substring}***](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html#AEN22664) string operation, so this almost works:

```
for i in `ls`; do mv $i ${i#[0-9]}; done
```

However, this removes only a single digit and adding regex '+' does not seem to work. Is there a way to strip ALL preceding digits characters?

Thank you!

Comment: `${i#[0-9]*-}`   ..

Comment: But it's not a regex, it's a glob.

Comment: be careful with constructs like "for i in `ls`" .  `for` uses the `$IFS` to split the input items, and that by default includes spaces.  I prefer ` find -print0 | xargs -0 ` for this reason.  `+` is part of extended regular expressions, but not the original regular expressions historically implemented by `grep`, `sed`, etc.

Comment: A very similar question about removing numbers from the begining of a file name was asked two days ago on Unix+Linux: [How do I remove any and all characters before the first period in a file name?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/600246/how-do-i-remove-any-and-all-characters-before-the-first-period-in-a-file-name)

Comment: Thanks John, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a single character that always marks the end of the prefix, [Pattern Matching](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern) makes it very simple.

```
for f in *; do
  mv -nv "$f" "${f#*-}";
done;
```

---

Things worth noting:

In your case, the use of `ls` does not cause problems, but for a more generalized solution, certain filenames would break it. Additionally, the lack of quotes around parameter expansions would cause issues for files with newlines, spaces or tabs in them.

The pattern `*-` matches any string ending with `-` combined with [lazy prefix removal](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#from_the_beginning) (one `#` instead of 2), leads to `${f#*-}` evaluating to `"$f"` with the shortest prefix ending in `-` removed (if one exists).

Bash's pattern matching is different from and inferior to RegEx, but you can get a little more power by enabling [extended pattern matching](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern#extended_pattern_language) with `shopt -s extglob`. Some distributions have this enabled by default.

Also, I threw the `-nv` flags in `mv` to ensure no mishaps when playing around with parameter expansion.

---

More Pattern Matching tricks I often use:

If you want to remove all leading digits and don't always have a single character terminating the prefix, extended pattern matching is helpful: `"${f##+([0-9])}"`

Answer (score 3):

With Perl's standalone `rename` command:

```
rename -n 's/.*?-//' *.txt
```

If output looks okay, remove `-n`.

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure if something is wrong on my end but this does not do anything, no output. `rename from util-linux 2.35.2`

Comment: @Norskyi  That `rename` is, unfortunately, incompatible with perl's.  To get perl's rename, have a look [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148379/delete-spaces-hyphens-and-underscores-in-filenames/148380#148380).

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in * 
do

name=$( echo "$i" | cut -d "-" -f 2 )
mv "$i" "$name" 2>/dev/null

done
```